# Mathematica DSolve for two functions

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I have the following two differential equations

```
y'[t] == k1*y[t] - k3*y2[t]
y2'[t] == k2*y2[t] - k4*y[t]
```

I can solve the equations using Mathematicas DSolve Function:

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == k1*y[t] - k3*y2[t], y2'[t] == k2*y2[t] - k4*y[t], 
   y[0] == y10, y2[0] == y20}, {y[t], y2[t]}, t]
```

Mathematica gives me the analytical result of this system of differential equations, in the following form:

```
y[t] = f{t}
```

and

```
y2[t] f{t}
```

But what I want is a function for y[t] that depends not only on t, but also on y2[t]

```
y[t] = f{t, y2[t]}
```

The reason is that I have experimental data (the concentrations y and y2 over t) and I want to fit a curve for y (and later y2). I am thankful for any input! :-)

Comment: Looks like the code posted is incomplete or incorrect. The `Solve` evaluates to `{{}}`.

Comment: Do you really want `f(t, y2)`? This sounds a bit arbitrary as `y2` also depends on `t`. I would understand if you needed `f(y2)`, but depending on both variables will not give you a unique result. It is like saying you want the volume of a cube based on its side length `a` and base area `A(a) = a^2`. This could give you a multitude of solutions, including `V(a, A) = a^3 = a^2 * sqrt(A) = a * A = A^(3/2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your input.
The thing is, that I have measured y and y2 (which are concentrations of differenent substances during a chemical reaction) over time (8 samples within 60 minutes). Now i want to fit a kinetic model to the concentration courses. Therefore, i thought it would be a good idea to have an equation y2 = f(y2, t). 

Another idea that came: Is it be to fit both functions with shared parameters (The k's have to be the same for both functions)?

Answer (score 0):

I would have just left this as a comment, but I can't (too low reputation), but Trying a simplification of your code:

```
DSolve[{D[y1[t, y2[t]], t] == 3*y1[t, y2[t]],   D[y2[t], t] == 2*y1[t, y2[t]], y1[0, 0] 
== 0, 
y2[0] == 2}, {y1[t, y2[t]], y2[t]}, t]
```

Produces the error

```
DSolve::ivar2: The independent variable t should not appear in two different arguments of the dependent variable y1[t,y2[t]].
```

So I'm not entirely sure if you can get Mathematica to do what you are asking for, if I understand what you wanted correctly. I suggest asking at [The Mathematica Stack Exchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com), Since they are most likely much more experienced with these types of issues.